# Enable JMX port Amazon Java cerretto

Tags: java, corretto

I am trying to enable jmx port on amazon corretto (amazon-corretto-11.0.5.10.1-linux-x64). MyJVM has the following JVM arguments

```
"-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=true"
 "-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9971" 
"-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false" 
"-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false"'
```

But when i try to launch jvisual VM it says "Not supported for this JVM".
Any suggestions how can I enable jmx port for this jvm. the same arguments work for java 8 jvms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JMX is supported in the latest Corretto, and you'll need to upgrade to 11.0.10.

> bin/java -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=true
> -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9971 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -version openjdk version "11.0.10" 2021-01-19 LTS OpenJDK Runtime Environment
> Corretto-11.0.10.9.1 (build 11.0.10+9-LTS) OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM
> Corretto-11.0.10.9.1 (build 11.0.10+9-LTS, mixed mode)

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem with amazon-corretto-8, and after testing with various other JVM and version seems that the problem reside on the RMI exposed port used by JMX.

A working configuration for amazon corretto 8 (but I think for actually the most used jvm out there) is this:

```
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9081
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.host=127.0.0.1
-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=127.0.0.1
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=9080
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=true
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
```

WARNING - This configuration accept only local connection and is intended for access through an SSH tunnel